# LuaLaTeX + luatexja + beamer: Serif vs. Sans-Serif

Tags: beamer, fonts, luatex, japanese, luatexja

- I wanted to create a **`beamer`** presentation in which **Japanese** and English are mixed.
- According to my Google-Fu, the **[`luatexja`](https://ctan.org/pkg/luatexja)** package is good for that.
- In principle, it was surprisingly easy to use. I even don't know which Japanese font is used - it just worked.
- My problem is that the **non-bold text is serif** and the **bold text is sans-serif** (for Japanese).
- The goal is to have it **all sans-serif**.
- In case it is relevant, I use **TeXLive 2021** on **Windows 10**.

---

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{luatexja}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
Test (sans-serif \faThumbsUp)\\
\textbf{Test} (sans-serif \faThumbsUp)\\
ォテ (serif \faThumbsDown)\\
\textbf{ォテ} (sans-serif \faThumbsUp)
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Remark:** I tried the `match` option from the `luatexja` package but this does not seem to change the output.
[image]

---

**Remark:** Just for completeness, in the `article` document class it is like this:

```
\documentclass[t]{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{luatexja}

\begin{document}

%\begin{frame}{Test}
\noindent
Test (serif)\\
\textbf{Test} (serif)\\
ォテ (serif)\\
\textbf{ォテ} (sans-serif)
%\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: beamer presentation in which Japanese for the Tokyo 2020 olympiads? :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano Haha :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As documented in section 2.4 of the manual:

> If you use the beamer class with the default font theme (which uses sans serif fonts) and with LuaTEX-
> ja, you might want to change default Japanese fonts to the gothic family. The following line changes
> the default Japanese font family to it:
>
> ```
> \renewcommand{\kanjifamilydefault}{\gtdefault}
> ```

By default this will give you bold text, but you can load a fontfamily supporting multiple weights of gothic using the `luatexja-preset` package. You have to pass the `deluxe` option if you want multiple weights:

> - `deluxe`
>
>   Use the mincho family with three weights (light, medium, and bold), the gothic family with three
>   weights (medium, bold, and extra bold), and rounded gothic. [...]

You can read the documentation for all the supported presets, here I will use Noto (on Windows you might want to replace `noto-otf` with e.g. `yu-win10` to avoid performance issues):

```
\documentclass[t]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{luatexja}
\usepackage[deluxe,noto-otf]{luatexja-preset}
\renewcommand{\kanjifamilydefault}{\gtdefault}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test}
Test (sans-serif \faThumbsUp)\\
\textbf{Test} (sans-serif \faThumbsUp)\\
ォテ (gothic \faThumbsUp)\\
\textbf{ォテ} (gothic \faThumbsUp)
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! The very good manual was a bit too complicated for my skill level.

Comment: Would you suggest that I stick with this approach or would you suggest that I use another approach (package) for creating this kind of output (beamer, Japanese, and English mixed)?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I never wrote anything in Japanese, so I don't have enough experience to give a qualified answer to this. But as far as I know `luatexja` should be the best option, especially since the documentation mentions `beamer` so the combination is probably well tested.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I just saw on your profile that you are very involved in LaTeX. Thank you for that incl. fontawesome5.

Comment: I tried to use `\usepackage[deluxe,yu-win10]{luatexja-preset}` as recommended and got `! Package fontspec Error: The font "YuMincho-Regular" cannot be found.`. Do I download the font using TeXLiVe's package manager or do I install it as a system font? In my MS Word, the font is available.